# WMF 5.0 (KB3134760) install failure, bad certificate?

Tags: windows-update, certificate

I am trying to install WMF 5.0 on a 64-bit Win7-SP1 machine using Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu downloaded from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395

The installation fails, leaving this message in the Setup log in Event Viewer:

> Windows update "Update for Windows (KB3134760)" could not be installed
>   because of error 2148204801 "A required certificate is not within its
>   validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the
>   timestamp in the signed file."

It appears that the certificate on the .msu file is valid from 6/4/2015 to 9/4/2016, so it is indeed expired. To view this information, I right click on the .msu file in Explorer, select Properties, then Digital Signatures, select the Microsoft signature and click Details, then click View Certificate.

Is this really a problem with the .msu file from Microsoft? Or do I need to update the certificates or something on my computer? If I need to update something, how would I go about that?

I tried rolling back system time to fall in the validity window of the certificate, but the installation still fails.

Comment: The certificate that expired, is the certificate, that signed the file.  The file would have to be released again, in order to not produce this error, and signed with a new certificate.  Typically you would remove the certificate from a file liekt his to get past this problem.

Comment: So the solution is to install the certificate then manually move the certificate so it will be trusted.  An expired certificate does not become unsafe automatically